# Envers with Nhibernate - SetEnversProperty

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

I'm attempting to setup NHibernate.Envers to use a separate database, schema and table suffix. For some reason, the configuration changes I'm setting at being ignored.

**Example Code**

```
var nhCfg = new Configuration().Configure();
nhCfg.IntegrateWithEnvers(new AttributeConfiguration());
nhCfg.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.AuditTableSuffix, "_Log");
nhCfg.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.DefaultCatalog, "LoggingDatabase");
nhCfg.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.DefaultSchema, "log");
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm not sure if I am missing something to commit the configuration change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set envers properties before calling IntegrateWithEnvers.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I missed!